# give a role access to specific folder in Sitecore 6.5

Tags: sitecore

I have a user who's been assigned the sitecore/Analytics Reporting role (member of Sitecore Client Users), and when I log in with that user I can see Marketing Center, Engagement Analytics and Executive Dashboard. I now want to give this user read access to a content item, but I can't make it work.

First of all, the sitecore/Analytics Reporting role already has read access to the content editor etc (inherited from the Everyone role), so why can't I see it? I created another role with explicit read access to the content item and assigned it to the same user, but I still can't see it. Does anyone know what I need to do for the user to see the content item?

Comment: What do you see in the Access Viewer for this user?

Comment: It's got read access to the content folder (write, rename, create, delete and administer is denied).

Comment: Does the new role have read access to the parent and ancestors of the item?

Comment: Yep, it's got read access to all of them.

Comment: Could it be a hidden item or located in a hidden folder? You as administrator will see those, but your user can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking with Sitecore support they told me you have to add Sitecore Client Designer to your role (even though the Access Viewer shows you have read access you still won't be able to see it until you've added this role).

Answer (score 0):

I seen this a few times before with older Sitecore versions. Doing a Sitecore cache clear or IIS reset resolved it at that time.